# Issue saving files received via POST on a C server

Tags: c, post, server

For my class we are writing a server in C.

This server must have some websites available and receive and store any files it receives via POST. We already got the GET part with the websites, but when it comes to storing any incoming files we ended up in more of a trouble, I have created a parser to parse the request. But I have trouble saving the body of the request when it isnt plain text (and is instead an image, or a pdf document) and then storing it in the body of the request structure (to then be stored in a new file with the corresponding extension.

This is the code of my parser:

```
// Analiza la línea de solicitud HTTP para determinar el método, la ruta y el host
void parse_request_line(char *buffer, http_request *request)
{
    char *method_end = strchr(buffer, ' ');
    if (method_end == NULL)
    {
        request->method = UNSUPPORTED;
        return;
    }
    size_t method_len = method_end - buffer;
    if (strncmp(buffer, "GET", method_len) == 0)
    {
        request->method = GET;
    }
    else if (strncmp(buffer, "POST", method_len) == 0)
    {
        request->method = POST;
    }
    else if (strncmp(buffer, "PUT", method_len) == 0)
    {
        request->method = PUT;
    }
    else if (strncmp(buffer, "DELETE", method_len) == 0)
    {
        request->method = DELETE;
    }
    else
    {
        request->method = UNSUPPORTED;
    }
    printf("--> Método HTTP: %d\n", request->method);

    char *uri_start = method_end + 1;
    char *uri_end = strchr(uri_start, ' ');
    if (uri_end == NULL)
    {
        request->method = UNSUPPORTED;
        return;
    }
    size_t uri_len = uri_end - uri_start;
    char *http_version_start = uri_end + 1;
    if (http_version_start[0] != 'H' || http_version_start[1] != 'T' || http_version_start[2] != 'T' || http_version_start[3] != 'P' || http_version_start[4] != '/')
    {
        request->method = UNSUPPORTED;
        printf("-->http_version_start no comenza con HTTP/. ");
        return;
    }
    if (http_version_start[5] == '0')
    {
        strcpy(request->version, "HTTP/1.0");
        printf("-->HTTP version 1.0 detectado. \n");
    }
    else if (http_version_start[5] == '1')
    {
        strcpy(request->version, "HTTP/1.1 ");
        printf("-->HTTP version 1.1 detectado. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        request->method = UNSUPPORTED;
        printf("--> No se puede detectar la version de HTTP o no esta soportado. \n");
        return;
    }
    request->version[7] = '\0';
    char *uri = strndup(uri_start, uri_len);
    char *host_start = strstr(uri, "://");
    if (host_start)
    {
        host_start += 3;
        char *path_start = strchr(host_start, '/');
        if (path_start)
        {
            *path_start = '\0';
            path_start++;
            request->host = strdup(host_start);
            request->path = strdup(path_start);
        }
        else
        {
            request->host = strdup(host_start);
            request->path = strdup("");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Trata de obtener host desde antes

        char *host_start = strstr(method_end, "Host: ");
        if (host_start)
        {
            host_start += 6;
            char *host_end = strstr(host_start, "\r\n");
            size_t host_len = host_end - host_start;
            request->host = strndup(host_start, host_len);
        }
        else
        {
            request->host = strdup("");
        }
        request->path = strdup(uri);
    }
    printf("->> Host: %s\n", request->host);
    printf("->> Ruta: %s\n", request->path);
    free(uri);

    if (request->method == POST)
    {
        char *content_type_start = strstr(method_end, "Content-Type: ");
        if (content_type_start != NULL)
        {
            content_type_start += 14;
            char *content_type_end = strstr(content_type_start, "\r\n");
            size_t content_type_len = content_type_end - content_type_start;
            request->content_type = strndup(content_type_start, content_type_len);

            // Detectar el tipo de archivo y asignar la extensión correspondiente
            if (strncmp(request->content_type, "text/plain", 10) == 0) {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".txt");
            } else if (strncmp(request->content_type, "image/png", 9) == 0) {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".png");
            } else if (strncmp(request->content_type, "image/jpeg", 9) == 0) {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".jpeg");
            } else if (strncmp(request->content_type, "image/gif", 15) == 0) {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".gif");
            } else if (strncmp(request->content_type, "application/pdf", 15) == 0) {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".pdf");
            } else if (strncmp(request->content_type, "application/octet-stream", 24) == 0) {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".exe");
            } else {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".dat");
            }
        }

        char *content_length_start = strstr(method_end, "Content-Length: ");
        if (content_length_start != NULL)
        {
            content_length_start += 16; // saltar los caracteres de "Content-Length:"
            char *content_length_end = strstr(content_length_start, "\r\n");
            size_t content_length_len = content_length_end - content_length_start;
            char content_length_str[content_length_len + 1];
            strncpy(content_length_str, content_length_start, content_length_len);
            content_length_str[content_length_len] = '\0';
            request->content_len = strtol(content_length_str, NULL, 10);
        }
        

        char *body_start = strstr(buffer, "\r\n\r\n");
        if (body_start != NULL) 
        {
            body_start += 4; // saltar los caracteres de separación
            size_t buffer_len = strlen(buffer);
            size_t body_len = buffer + buffer_len - body_start - 4;
            request->body = (char*) malloc(body_len + 1); // incluir espacio adicional para NULL
            memcpy(request->body, body_start, body_len);
            request->body[body_len] = '\0'; // agregar byte NULL

            // Generar el nombre del archivo a partir de la fecha y hora
            time_t t = time(NULL);
            struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
            char filename[100];
            sprintf(filename, "%04d-%02d-%02d_%02d-%02d-%02d%s", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec, request->file_ext);


           // Guardar el archivo en disco
            int fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
            write(fd, request->body, request->content_len);
            //write(fd, request->body, body_len);
            close(fd);
        }
        printf("->> Body: %s\n", request->body);
    }
    printf("->> THE BUFFER: %s\n", buffer);
}
```

Specifically, The part that is the most important is the part after the method->POST condition, because only then we save the relevant data for the POST:

```
if (request->method == POST)
    {
        char *content_type_start = strstr(method_end, "Content-Type: ");
        if (content_type_start != NULL)
        {
            content_type_start += 14;
            char *content_type_end = strstr(content_type_start, "\r\n");
            size_t content_type_len = content_type_end - content_type_start;
            request->content_type = strndup(content_type_start, content_type_len);

            // Detectar el tipo de archivo y asignar la extensión correspondiente
            if (strncmp(request->content_type, "text/plain", 10) == 0) {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".txt");
            } else if (strncmp(request->content_type, "image/png", 9) == 0) {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".png");
            } else if (strncmp(request->content_type, "image/jpeg", 9) == 0) {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".jpeg");
            } else if (strncmp(request->content_type, "image/gif", 15) == 0) {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".gif");
            } else if (strncmp(request->content_type, "application/pdf", 15) == 0) {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".pdf");
            } else if (strncmp(request->content_type, "application/octet-stream", 24) == 0) {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".exe");
            } else {
                request->file_ext = strdup(".dat");
            }
        }

        char *content_length_start = strstr(method_end, "Content-Length: ");
        if (content_length_start != NULL)
        {
            content_length_start += 16; // saltar los caracteres de "Content-Length:"
            char *content_length_end = strstr(content_length_start, "\r\n");
            size_t content_length_len = content_length_end - content_length_start;
            char content_length_str[content_length_len + 1];
            strncpy(content_length_str, content_length_start, content_length_len);
            content_length_str[content_length_len] = '\0';
            request->content_len = strtol(content_length_str, NULL, 10);
        }
        

        char *body_start = strstr(buffer, "\r\n\r\n");
        if (body_start != NULL) 
        {
            body_start += 4; // saltar los caracteres de separación
            size_t buffer_len = strlen(buffer);
            size_t body_len = buffer + buffer_len - body_start - 4;
            request->body = (char*) malloc(body_len + 1); // incluir espacio adicional para NULL
            memcpy(request->body, body_start, body_len);
            request->body[body_len] = '\0'; // agregar byte NULL

            // Generar el nombre del archivo a partir de la fecha y hora
            time_t t = time(NULL);
            struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
            char filename[100];
            sprintf(filename, "%04d-%02d-%02d_%02d-%02d-%02d%s", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec, request->file_ext);


           // Guardar el archivo en disco
            int fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
            write(fd, request->body, request->content_len);
            //write(fd, request->body, body_len);
            close(fd);
        }
        printf("->> Body: %s\n", request->body);
    }
```

I have already tested with POSTMAN and the http_request struct is being saved as it should, except for the body of the request.
That is visible on the console when I try to send a simple png picture to the server:

```
pc@pc server % ./server              
Usando assets de  ./logs
Servidor iniciado en el puerto 8080...
--> Método HTTP: 1
-->HTTP version 1.1 detectado. 
->> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
->> Ruta: /test2
->> Body: �PNG
->> THE BUFFER: POST /test2 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 13ebab0b-b17c-4a89-916c-d0889bacd9f9
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 86054
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG


--Method: 1
--Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
--Path: /test2
--Body: �PNG
--Content-Length: 86054
--Content-Type: image/png
```

as we can see on the last lines starting with "--" (that is the data that gets stored on the struct) the data is being parsed correctly with the exception of the request's body, how can I properly save or parse the body of the request in order to be able to save the incoming files correctly?

We can compare the POSTMAN request in the buffer and the stored data and the Content-Length and Type seem correct, the path and method are ok as well. It's just the body what I'm having trouble managing. We also tried to use CURL in order to save the binaries but it seemed too messy for what we needed.

We just need to store any text/images/pdf people send us in the body of a POST request.

Sorry for any spelling mistake, I'm a bit sleep deprived, but any help is very much appreciated!!

Summary: We tried to store the data inside the request's body and save it into the new file using write, but it didn't save correctly when the request is a binary file instead of plain text.